# Minecraft Entity Following Player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to make an entity follow a player, such as an armor stand?
No mods please. I'm doing a vanilla minecraft project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this should be exactly what your looking for